# Extracting data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dataframe from which im trying to extract some data:

```
frame   id        type         truncated
0       -1      DontCare        -1
0       10        Car            0  
0       13       Misc            0
0       11        Car            1
0       12        Car            1
```

and I want to extract data related to the `Car` type. So what I did is:

```
 for column in labels['type'].items():
        if column == 'DontCare':
            continue
        if column == "Car" or "Van":
            print('car')
        else:
            print('no car')
```

But I get this error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read on how to properly [index and select data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `df[(df.Type=="Car") | (df.Type=="Van")]`

For example,

```
data = [['Car', 10], ['Van', 15], ['Car', 14], ['DNC', 11]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Type', 'Value']) 

print(df)
```

produces

```
    Type    Value
0   Car     10
1   Van     15
2   Car     14
3   DNC     11
```

and

```
print(df[(df.Type=="Car") | (df.Type=="Van")])
```

produces

```
    Type    Value
0   Car     10
1   Van     15
2   Car     14
```